# is there any plugin for edit inplace without sending any call to server in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to edit a paragraph in place, but the content will be saved to DB by clicking Save button for the page. I searched for edit in place plugin, but all I found all sends content to server. Is there any plugin which does the same without sending any data to server ?

Comment: Just curious - if you don't send data to the server, how is it supposed to be saved?

Comment: So are you looking for a control that uses AJAX to send the data to the server? Meaning it doesn't refresh the whole page but does it behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to edit a paragraph in place,
>   but the content will be saved to DB by
>   clicking Save utton for the page.

Actually, the content needs to be sent to the server for you to be able to save it into the database as you say you want to save it. You need a ***server***-side language as well as database system to save that. ***So, it needs to be sent to the server.***

Comment: well, that changed since `HTML5 storage`. Even without you might save data to cookies, which is not recommendable for large datasets, but possible.

Comment: @jAndy: I suppose, we are far far away from html5 thing now.

Comment: My requirement is - until user changes the content on a page, no data is sent to server. The content changes may be changes to  a single paragraph, a table or all. After user clicks on save button, the whole page will be (which is further subdivided) saved in DB. I'm not sure if this is feasible or not. :(

Comment: That's pretty much how all forms work. You make some changes, you click save and it goes to the database :)